# estimating the probability density function of a random variable $X$

Tags: probability-distributions, estimation

I have a random variable $X$ that is a sum of two non-independent random variables $X_1$ and $X_2$. Since $X_1$ and $X_2$ are non-independent, then convolution theorem cannot be used to find the pdf of $X$. With no other information on the relationship (covariance, etc) between $X_1$ and $X_2$, then it is ultimately difficult to derive the pdf of $X$. The distributions of $X_1$ and $X_2$ , however, are individually known.

So another 'strategy' must be used in order to derive the pdf of $X$. Fortunately, technology is available (Matlab) for simulations and histograms are made to run again and again. Now that we will be basing the pdf of $X$ from histograms, then I believe the correct word now should be 'estimating' the pdf of $X$.

Would you know of techniques that I should do/perform to be able to get this estimated pdf of $X$?

Comment: Never encountered something like that (word of comfort: my scope is a small one) and also (on intuition): not much faith in it. Btw, it could be that $X$ doesn't even has a PDF (e.g. if $X_2=-X_1)$.

Comment: $X=X_1 + X_2$, none of them is zero. I am not sure how the concept of 'estimators' play here. But I hope I am able to 'estimate' such a problem.

Comment: Google for "Kernel Density Estimation", and if you are commited to using Matlab add that to the search string.

Comment: Something wrong here. Extreme examples allowed by what you say: (1) $X_1 = X_2$, in which case $Y = X_1 = X_2 = 2X_1$.  (2) $X_1 = X_2$, in which case $Y$ is degenerate at 0. And many more. In general, there is much more information in a bivariate joint distribution than there is in either marginal. Also, why is nothing said about the distributions of the two random variables? This question should be put on hold pending some resolution.